# passing dictionary value from python to sql stored pocedure

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to pass a dictionary like

```
section value
1        10
2         3
```

Or list

```
section1 [10.2,3,4,5], section2 [1,a,10,"friend"]
```

From python to stored procedure of SQL Server. I connected to SQL Server using pyodbc,

```
from django.db import connection
```

In the stored procedure I need to write XML object based on this parameter. I could have created the table but I don't want to do many operation from python to SQL Server.

How do I do it?